# How can I pass a variable into a DataFrame.selectExpr

Tags: scala

I am running the following to get all states a doctor would have license in.

```
{
var srchExp = ""
for (i <- 1 to 15 )
  {`enter code here`
            srchExp = srchExp + s"'License Number $i',`Provider License Number_$i`,'Provider 
         License Number State Code_$i ',`Provider License Number State Code_$i`,"
            if (i == 15) {
                val srchLen = srchExp.length
                srchExp = srchExp.substring(0,srchLen-1)

  }
```

}
val finExp = """+"NPI"+"""+",s"+"""+"stack(15, "+srchExp + ") as (License,LicNumber,Code,State)" + """
println(finExp)
val retDF = npiDF.selectExpr(finExp) --- doesnt work
val retDF = npiDF.selectExpr(s"$finExp") --- doesnt work
val retDF = npiDF.selectExpr(finExp.toString) --- doesnt work
retDF
}

I can copy and paste the results of finExp into the selectExpr and it works just fine.  However when I use the val finExp in all the ways I tagged doesn't work above I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input ',' expecting {, '(', '.', '[', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', DATABASES, 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON', 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', 'OVER', 'OVERLAPS', 'OVERLAY', 'OVERWRITE', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONED', 'PARTITIONS', 'PERCENT', 'PIVOT', 'PLACING', 'POSITION', 'PRECEDING', 'PRIMARY', 'PRINCIPALS', 'PROPERTIES', 'PURGE', 'QUERY', 'RANGE', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'RECOVER', 'REDUCE', 'REFERENCES', 'REFRESH', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'RESTRICT', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', RLIKE, 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'SCHEMA', 'SELECT', 'SEMI', 'SEPARATED', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'SESSION_USER', 'SET', 'MINUS', 'SETS', 'SHOW', 'SKEWED', 'SOME', 'SORT', 'SORTED', 'START', 'STATISTICS', 'STORED', 'STRATIFY', 'STRUCT', 'SUBSTR', 'SUBSTRING', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'TBLPROPERTIES', TEMPORARY, 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TIME', 'TO', 'TOUCH', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'TRANSFORM', 'TRIM', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'UNBOUNDED', 'UNCACHE', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSET', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VIEW', 'VIEWS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', 'WITH', 'ZONE', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '&', '|', '||', '^', STRING, IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 5)

== SQL ==
"NPI","stack(15, 'License Number 1',`Provider License Number_1`,'Provider License Number State
-----^^^
Code_1 ',`Provider License Number State Code_1`,'License Number 2',`Provider License Number_2`,'Provider License Number State Code_2 ',`Provider License Number State Code_2`,'License Number 3',`Provider License Number_3`,'Provider License Number State Code_3 ',`Provider License Number State Code_3`,'License Number 4',`Provider License Number_4`,'Provider License Number State Code_4 ',`Provider License Number State Code_4`,'License Number 5',`Provider License Number_5`,'Provider License Number State Code_5 ',`Provider License Number State Code_5`,'License Number 6',`Provider License Number_6`,'Provider License Number State Code_6 ',`Provider License Number State Code_6`,'License Number 7',`Provider License Number_7`,'Provider License Number State Code_7 ',`Provider License Number State Code_7`,'License Number 8',`Provider License Number_8`,'Provider License Number State Code_8 ',`Provider License Number State Code_8`,'License Number 9',`Provider License Number_9`,'Provider License Number State Code_9 ',`Provider License Number State Code_9`,'License Number 10',`Provider License Number_10`,'Provider License Number State Code_10 ',`Provider License Number State Code_10`,'License Number 11',`Provider License Number_11`,'Provider License Number State Code_11 ',`Provider License Number State Code_11`,'License Number 12',`Provider License Number_12`,'Provider License Number State Code_12 ',`Provider License Number State Code_12`,'License Number 13',`Provider License Number_13`,'Provider License Number State Code_13 ',`Provider License Number State Code_13`,'License Number 14',`Provider License Number_14`,'Provider License Number State Code_14 ',`Provider License Number State Code_14`,'License Number 15',`Provider License Number_15`,'Provider License Number State Code_15 ',`Provider License Number State Code_15`) as (License,LicNumber,Code,State)"

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Parse exception error is because it is unable to parse the ","

use split(",")

For eg:-

```
infa_seq_no=2
parseString ='infa_seq_no * 2 as output2,infa_seq_no * 3 as output3'
df.selectExpr(parseString.split(",")).printSchema
```